# Basic geosearch with ElasticSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb

I'm putting together a proof of concept on AWS using Dynamo and the Amazon ElasticSearch service, and I'm having some trouble getting

I've checked the ES Dashboard and see the following....

I have an index [assets] and a mapping [asset_types]. Below is a sample of some the mappings, with the relevant location

```
filename *string*
checksum *string*
added_date *date*
General [this is a map]
    location 
        lat *string*
        lon *string*
    make *string*
    model *string*
```

I want the geo searches to be on the "General.location" field. I've tried a couple different queries so far without any luck, but I'm sure I'm missing something rather obvious.

One is from the official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html) ,modified to the below which results with this error:
"reason": "failed to parse search source. unknown search element [bool]",

```
POST assets/_search
{
    "bool" : {
        "must" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "200km",
                "General.location" : {
                    "lat" : 40,
                    "lon" : -70
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried a slightly different query which raises ""reason": "failed to find geo_point field [General.location]"

```
POST assets/_search
{
   "filter" : {
      "geo_distance" : {
         "distance" : "1km",
         "General.location" : {
                        "lat" : 40,
                        "lon" : -70
                    }
      }
   },
   "query" : {
      "match_all" : {}
   }
}
```

Am I running a query incorrectly? Do I need to update the mapping in the index to specify the geo-index? I thought if I formatted fields properly that wasn't a requirement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in your mapping, where your `General.location` field is not properly mapped. That's the reason you get the error `failed to find geo_point field`

So instead of

```
General [this is a map]
    location 
        lat *string*
        lon *string*
```

You need to have

```
General [this is a map]
    location *geo_point*
```

So you need to modify your mapping accordingly and reindex your data.

The second issue you have is that your first query needs to be enclosed in a `query` section:

```
POST assets/_search
{
  "query" : {
     "bool" : {
        "must" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "200km",
                "General.location" : {
                    "lat" : 40,
                    "lon" : -70
                }
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Once you've fixed both issues, you'll be able to run your query successfully.

Comment: Thanks Val. You were correct. I could have sworn I read that if you set up your input in the correct format it would read in a geo_point. Sounds like that wasn't exactly the case.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Val said, I created a new mapping for location

I explicitly created a mapping for this. Note for you other novices out there, I needed to use nested properties update in order to create  the "General.deviceLocation". After I did this, Val's update query worked.

```
PUT assets/_mapping/assets_type
{
  "properties": {
    "General": {
      "properties": {
        "deviceLocation": {  
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    },
  }
}
```